# Decrypting a BitLocker-ed that uses TPM

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, disk-encryption, bitlocker, tpm

I'm looking at Dislocker but i cant figure out if a drive that is locked using TPM, but has those details stored in AD, can be opened using Dislocker. Does anyone know?

EDIT: Dislocker is a linux driver that decrypts Bitlockered Drives. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt a drive locked using BitLocker and the TPM by using your Bitlocker recovery key. You'd typically put the recovery key on a USB flash drive and then use it when unlocking the encrypted drive. Just click on 'Get the key from a USB flash drive' during the unlock process.

Comment: I dont understand why you edited my question. I said Dislocker and i meant dislocker. I want use both a pin/ password and a TPM. I know that i can get the password from AD but is what is stored in AD for the TPM what i need to decrypt it?

Comment: I don't know of a locker (apart from BitLocker) that stores recovery agent data in AD...

Comment: @tpmbuster, dislocker is a Linux tool and you didn't mention Linux anywhere. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sorry! i realised i was being confusing! Dislocker is a linux driver that decrypts Bitlockered Drives.